# sort array of date of format 'dd/mmm/yyyy'

Tags: knockout.js

```
var data=ko.observableArray[(
{mydate:'01 Jan 1997'},
{mydate:'01 Aug 1977'},
)];
```

I want to sort above data in ascending and descending order on click of button.
Plz help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way to sort an observableArray,

**Option  1** 
simply use string sort,

**ViewModel**

```
$(function () {
function VM() {
var self = this;
self.data = ko.observableArray([
    {mydate: '01 Jan 1997'},
    {mydate: '01 Aug 1977'},
]);
self.stringSort = function (a, b) {
    return a.mydate.toLowerCase() > b.mydate.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
};
self.stringSortInstances = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    return self.data.slice().sort(self.stringSort);
}, self);

}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:stringSortInstances ">
     <li data-bind="text:$data.mydate"></li>
 </ul>
```

**Option - 2**
here you need to change the observableArray value format,then convert the string to date and sort. it will sort based on the date.

**View Model**

```
$(function () {
function VM() {
self.dataInUniDateFormate = ko.observableArray([
    {mydate: '1997/01/01'},
    {mydate: '1977/08/01'},
]);
self.dateSort = function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a.mydate) > new Date(b.mydate) ? 1 : -1;
};
self.DateSortInstances = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    return self.dataInUniDateFormate.slice().sort(self.dateSort);
}, self);
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
});
```

**html**

```
 <p>Date Sort</p>
        <ul data-bind="foreach:DateSortInstances">
            <li data-bind="text:$data.mydate"></li>
        </ul>
```

**option 3** you can use some external plugin to convert your string to date and then sort. You can use [dateformater](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)  or [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) or any other date conversion plugins

thanks and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @prasadparab then mark it as answer,may be in future it will help some other.